# How to create desktop application using R language?

Tags: javascript, r

I have started learning `R`. I searched for the steps/ways to create application in `R`. But I have not yet found any manuals on that. Can someone guide the correct packages used for creating a desktop app in `R`? or help with the code itself?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: [http://www.r-bloggers.com/look-ma-no-typing-autorunning-code-on-r-startup/](http://www.r-bloggers.com/look-ma-no-typing-autorunning-code-on-r-startup/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-guis-in-r-with-gwidgets/

> The gWidgets framework is a way of creating graphical user interfaces in a toolkit independent way.  That means that you can choose between tcl/tk, Gtk, Java or Qt underneath the bonnet. There’s also a web-version based upon RApache and ExtJS.

About web integration features, take a look at the [RApache project](https://jeffreyhorner.github.io/rapache/manual.html) for documentation and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cant able to understand that, how to create a desktop application in R? Honestly I am not knowing what is desktop application in R. It is EXE?

Comment: R is an interpreted language, not a compiled language. So by default you don't get an executable, your program remains as a .r script to be executed by the R interpreter. If you want an EXE launcher, you will have to embed your script into a compiled language such as C++, see RInside http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html for more info

Comment: Thanks for the reply pwned. It is possible to run the R code without using the command prompt?

Comment: Are you asking if you can run executables without command prompt?

Comment: No. I am asking about the RScript or R file?

Comment: Are you asking if you can associate .r files with the R interpreter in a windows environment?

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. I got the solution of my problem. I have created the desktop application using R and run it in the command line. Now I am started developing web application in MAC. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

**What is R?**

- Open Source Programming Language

**Usages**

- Statistical Computing & Graphics purpose
- Widely use for Data Analysis

**Supports**

- Simple procedural Language
- Using Functions and Object-Oriented Concepts as well
- Use as Data mining tool as well
- R-Graphics provide Statical Graphics as well

**Languages**

You can call R with a simple Java reference (so, you can easily call written Java scripts easily on R). You can also apply **web-based** services with the RApache and ExtJS

Hope this information will help you making your first step in R.

Comment: Thanks. your post helps me. Can you please explain, how to create desktop application in R?

Comment: Add RStudio in your system... will provide you full-fledged information about creating desktop application..

Comment: I have already installed RStudio and R in my machine. Whether running Rscript in the RStudio IDE is the desktop application? Or how to make it as desktop application?

Comment: basically, that one is known as desk applications...and R used for generally making finance related software, and R-Graphics will provide the best platform for the same.

Comment: So, the finance related software which is developed using R language is known as Desktop application. My understanding is correct?

Comment: Would you mind editing your post to use proper language, eg s/U/you/?

Comment: That's the wrong one...!!! but developers usually use R for making those type of application...

Comment: Another one doubt Viral. Always we want to run the Rscript from the command line?

Comment: Yes, there are no stand alone UI/SDK available for it.

Comment: Thanks Viral. Thanks for your reply. My problem is 50 % getting cleared.